# Anticipate how Excel will interpret a string using Postgres function

Tags: c#, excel, perl, postgresql

With my workplace, we have part number (item numbers), that, when typed into Excel often get converted into what Excel *thinks* the user means.

For example, Excel makes these changes:

```
00001234   =>   1234
005678.0   =>   5678
1234.560   =>   1234.56
```

Because the spreadsheets come from sources outside our control, we cannot attempt to control the behavior in Excel itself.

I have a utility that's bolted onto Excel, using VSTO (C#), that goes out to a Postgres table and attempts to look up the "Excel part number" and convert it back to the real part number.  Simply put, it looks like this:

```
create table mdm.excel_lookup (
    actual_part_number text not null,
    excel_part_number text not null,
    lookup_priority integer not null,
    constraint excel_lookup_pk primary key (actual_part_number)
);
```

To populate this table, I have written a function using plperl that attempt to take any given string and anticipate how Excel will mess it up.  I believe I have handled numbers with leading zeros and also trailing zeros that are chopped off after the decimal place.

Unfortunately this doesn't cover everything.  I don't think Dates will be possible to anticipate, so I may not even try, unless someone has a great idea.  But what about scientific notation?  Are there other scenarios I haven't thought of?

Our part catalog has over 1.5 million parts, so there are numerous possibilities of what might happen.  If I can capture a fair percentage of them, I'd be happy.

Here is my function thus far.  If anyone has ideas on what I can do to capture additional things that Excel might do, I would welcome the feedback.  Note this, so far, only handles the scenarios I've listed above.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION excel_part(part_number text)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$

  my ($input) = @_;
  if ($input =~ /[A-Za-z]/) {
    return $input;
  } elsif ($input =~ /^0+(\d+)$/) {
    return $1;
  } elsif ($input =~ /^(\d+\.\d*)0+$/) {
    return $1 + 0;
  } else {
    return $input;
  }  

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plperl VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Also, I am not married to plperl.  I used it only because I know Perl is really good at text handling.

Comment: Do you get those files as CSV or XLS?

Comment: @simbabque -- that's a good question.  They come in as Excel native files.  I do know that Excel will also honk up perfectly good CSV files, but in this case the honking was done prior to us getting it

Comment: If you can provide them presets you can fix the cell formating and lock certain things. That might help. Also note different local versions of Excel break stuff differently.

Comment: The main problem is we can't control the source.  The data comes to us from any number of sources, including outside vendors and automated jobs.  We control as much as we can, but there are still spreadsheets that come in second, third, fourth-hand where we cannot trace back to the origin

Comment: Are you using the excel files directly downstream or is there an import job that reads those into a product database? You might be able to fix more based on a set of rules with perl or something else that's good at automatically reading and writing the files. Maybe have a full set of coercion rules to fix them based on patterns instead of a lookup. I like the challenge of this question.

Comment: We are fixing them directly from the spreadsheet.  I have written a C# extension to Excel (using VSTO) that goes out to Postgres and evaluates the "excel-ized" part against the list of real, valid parts.  It runs very quickly, even for thousands of parts.  It is a fun puzzle, but also frustrating.  We recently joined with another company, which is why this issue is new -- a list of new ways Excel can mess up strings

Comment: You're going to have to convert both the Excel and PostgreSQL representations into a common form. e.g. for numbers: convert the part number from Excel and from PostgreSQL into a fixed-precision decimal and compare them. Your function must handle scientific notation, etc. The biggest problem you're going to have is some idiot using binary floating point so you get a part `142.00199999` instead of `142.002` or whatever. You'll need some form of rounding, but that's going to be hard if your part numbers don't have a fixed limit on the number of decimal places. Or if they can have multiple periods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to extract all your part numbers to excel, save the file after it has finished munging your numbers, then upload the results back to your database as a new table (or a column in the original table). That way you don't have to worry about any cases you didn't handle. It also allows you to index the column if you often do lookups based on this and easily detect any part numbers that end up becoming duplicates after they are munged.

You'll have to have some way to determine what they were before excel got to them though to re-uploaded. If there's a surrogate Id column, you can use that, otherwise do something simple like prefixing the part number with "Part-" so that excel will see a string and not touch it.

And if simbabque is correct and different excel versions do different things, you can just run this process through multiple different versions of excel and save the unique munges.

Comment: I meant different language/country versions, not releases. That happens because the users enter dates differently in different countries, and because decimal points and commas are handled differently. Stuff that has a `.` like `12.12` will be turned into a date in a German Excel and especially when exported to CSV will look like `12. Dez` or something like that. On the other hand, stuff that has `,` will be treated as text most likely in a US Excel, but in a German one it's a floating point number.

Comment: TimTom -- a brilliantly simple solution -- just as an FYI, I have posted how I actually implemented this to be "hand's free."  @simbabque -- all very relevant points; we are global, and I will probably have to find a way to run this program with various regional settings to ensure I maximize the chances of correctly fixing each part.  THANKS TO ALL.

Answer (score 0):

In response to Tim Tom's answer, this is a C# program that implements his suggestion...  and I it works great!

```
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection();
    conn.Open();

    Excel.Application xl = new Excel.Application();
    xl.Visible = true;
    Excel.Workbook wb = xl.Workbooks.Add(1);
    Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets[1];

    List<string> parts = new List<string>();

    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select prod_id from mdm.global_item_master",
        conn);
    NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
        parts.Add(reader.GetString(0));

    reader.Close();

    NpgsqlCopyIn copy = new NpgsqlCopyIn(
        "copy mdm.excel_item_id from STDIN WITH NULL AS '' CSV;", conn);
    copy.Start();

    NpgsqlCopySerializer cs = new NpgsqlCopySerializer(conn);
    cs.Delimiter = ",";

    foreach (string part in parts)
    {
        ws.Cells[1, 1].Value2 = part;

        cs.AddString(part);
        cs.AddString(ws.Cells[1, 1].Text);
        cs.EndRow();
    }

    cs.Close();
    copy.End();

    conn.Close();
```